# Is my Node/Express-based authentication implementation with session properly done?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, session, express.js

I **know that Passport.js exists**, however, I wanted to code my own implementation using express-session module.

I'm using:

- Express
- Mongoose
- express-session

So I basically have 2 routes for handling auth, `POST /signup` and `POST /login`.

This is what I've got, which I think is actually working but what I'm more concerned about is the session-handling.

```
var Account = require('../models/account');

app.route('/login')

    .post(function (request,response,next) {

        var email = request.body.email
        var password = request.body.password
        var login = new Account({"local.email":email,"local.password":password})

        Account.findOne({"local.email":email}, function (err,user) {

            if (err) {
                                response.send(500).end()
                                next();
            }

            if (!user) {
                                response.send(404).end();
                                next();
            }

            user.validPassword(password, function (err,matched) {

                if (err) {

                                response.status(500).end();
                                next();
                }

                if (matched) {

                                var session = request.session
                                session.name = email                                            
                                response.redirect('/start')
                                next();
                }
                else {
                                response.redirect('/')                                    
                                next();
                }
            })
        })
    })

    .delete(function (request,response) {

        request.session.destroy(function (err) {
            response.redirect('/')
        })
    })

app.route('/signup')

    .post(function (request,response) {

        var doc = new Account({"local.email":request.body.email,"local.password":request.body.password})

        doc.save(function (err,saved) {

            if (err) response.status(500).end();

            response.status(200).end();
        })
    })
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is whether it's properly implemented. Shit I actually had a question but it was edited and so dropped off!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it to the post body.  It should be in there instead of in the title.

Comment: It's OK Jamal, thanks for your edit though

Answer (score 3):

Heyo!

This is pretty good, but doesn't have any password hashing (storing your passwords in plain text is bad).

You might want to instead consider using an authentication library like either [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) or [stormpath](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/).

If you're really set on rolling your own auth stuff, you could use this project I wrote as an example (it's using the same tools you are): https://github.com/rdegges/svcc-auth

**UPDATE**: Since I was asked to show a Stormpath example, here ya go!

```
var express = require('express');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

var app = express();
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  apiKeyId: 'xxx',  // get this from your stormpath account
  apiKeySecret: 'xxx',  // get this from your stormpath account
  secretKey: 'some_long_random_string',  // this is used to encrypt sessions
  application: 'xxx',  // create a stormpath app, then copy the href here
}));

app.listen(3000);
```

That's it! The above code will automatically generate a registration, login, and logout page at /register, /login, and /logout, respectively.

Comment: I am doing password hashing at the Mongoose model, before being saved ti DB, password gets hashed

Comment: Could you offer an example of stormpath auth?

Comment: Btw I just read your site and it would be even greater as you're a stormpath evangelist!

Comment: Just edited my answer to include a stormpath example =)